# swapAdapter() is is refreshing RecyclerView view but not the data - Android - Java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

The recyclerView is used to display a custom ArrayList of products and this view can be switched between different types of products by the user via radio buttons that call swapAdapter.  The products are all filtered by diameter via spinner bar selection, and since the user will want to get products of matching diameter, the filter must hold as the adapters swap.  All of this is working in the view, however when the user selects an item to add to the cart, the cart will show the wrong item. It will be from the same position however, from the previous adapter.  As these adapters switch so does the last adapter. Why are the views refreshing but the data linked to the position is always one and only one step behind?

Here is the RecyclerView

```
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.inventory_recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        aAdapter = new CustomAdapter(aList);
        bAdapter = new CustomAdapter(bList);
        cAdapter = new CustomAdapter(cList);
        dAdapter = new CustomAdapter(dList);
        eAdapter = new CustomAdapter(eList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
```

and here is the radio group

```
 bButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(bAdapter, true);
               bAdapter.getFilter().filter(filterDiameterString);
            //   bAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        cButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(cAdapter, true);
             cAdapter.getFilter().filter(filterDiameterString);
           //  cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        dButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(dAdapter, true);
                dAdapter.getFilter().filter(filterDiameterString);
               // dAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        eButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(miscAdapter, true);
                eAdapter.getFilter().filter(filterDiameterString);
              //  eAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

The following has been attempted:
notifyDataSetChange
recyclerview.invalidate
adapter.clear()

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding a setter to my arraylist in the custom adapter and then changed the list via the setter then called notify data set change.